# Using nested interfaces and mapper with MyBatis

Tags: java, mybatis

Is it possible to use nested mapper interface?:

```
package com.sample.package;

public class SampleService{

  public interface SampleMapper{
    public List<MyEntity> selectAllEntities();
  }
}
```

And if yes:

- where to put mapper xml file?
- what should be the name of xml file?
- what namespace shoud I put in mapper xml file for interface?

Answer (score 0):

It works.

- The name of mapper must be SampleService$SampleMapper.xml.
- It must be placed in the SampleService dir.
- Namespace is com.sample.package.SampleService$SampleMapper.